# PyQt4 send signal on button click to other window

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have 2 windows created by 2 classes, both windows contains simulations. I want both of them started by click of the same button in first window. Should I use something like:

```
self.connect(self, SIGNAL("mysignal"), self.myValChanged)

            param = 100
            self.emit(SIGNAL("mysignal"), param)
```

in first window and

```
def myValChanged(val):
            print "New spin val %d" % val
```

in the second window? Will it work? How to use that?

My code:

```
class Simulation(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, filename, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("gui/mainui.ui", self)
        self.ui.startButton.clicked.connect(self.onStartButtonClick)
        self.pos = [0, 0]
        self.v0 = 10.0
        self.pts = []
        self.isMoving = False
        self.force = Force()
        self.loadData(filename)
        self.movement = Movement(self.force, self.pts, self)

    def onStartButtonClick(self):
        if(self.isMoving == False):
            self.pos = [0, 0]
            self.v0 = 10.0
            self.isMoving = True
            self.move()
            #start differentmove() from second class

    def move(self):
    ...


class Simulation2(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, filename, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("gui/mainui2.ui", self)
        self.ui.startButton.clicked.connect(self.onStartButtonClick)
        self.pos = [400, 0]
        self.v0 = 10.0
        self.pts = []
        self.isMoving = False
        self.force = Force()
        self.loadData(filename)
        self.movement = Movement(self.force, self.pts, self)

    def differentmove(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Where do you show the first window and where do you show the second window? Where are there references (objects)?